# Erro Node.js v6.11.5 no Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

Instalei Node.js para estudar Angular 2, eu baixei pelo site do node, mas depois de instalar, quando eu digito `npm start` no cmd do meu PC, eu recebo o erro abaixo, estou dando o comando na pasta do arquivo `package.json` `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver? Por favor! :)

```
C:\Users\Sarah Santana>node -v
v6.11.5

C:\Users\Sarah Santana>cd\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm>npm start
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npm-debug.log.3610650318
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npm-debug.log.3610650318'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npm-debug.log.3610650318'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\npm-debug.log.3610650318' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: você deve executar dentro via linha de comando dentro da pasta/diretório de sua aplicação exemplo: `cd C:\Users\Sarah Santana\Desktop\your_project_path` nesta pasta execute `npm start` se seu projeto possuir um arquivo *package.json* com a entrada "scripts.start"

Comment: @LauroMoraes, coloque como resposta, vou remover a minha pois você comentou antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente você esta executando o comando `npm start` no local errado... você esta executando dentro da pasta de instalação no `NodeJs`.

Você deve criar uma pasta para seu projeto e nela adicionar o arquivo **.js** de execução de sua aplicação. Para usar o comando `npm start` deve haver em sua pasta um arquivo **package.json** com as instruções para carregar "scripts" exemplo:

**index.js**

```
// um simples console
console.log('Hello World!')
```

**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "nome-de-sua-aplicação",
   "main": "index.js",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "scripts": {
       "start": "index"
   }
}
```

Note que o arquivo **package.json** pode pode conter muitas informações sendo neste exemplo ao utilizar `npm start` sera executado o arquivo dentro da instrução `scripts.start` através deste comando também é possível adicionar argumentos opcionais.

**Referencias**

NPM Documentação [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

NPM Documentação [comando start](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start)

---

**edição**

Note: o exemplo acima sugere-se utilizar dentro de diretórios comuns ao usuário (área de trabalho, documentos, etc...) contudo o seu `log` de erro reporta falta de privilégios administrativos pois estava sendo executado dentro de pastas comumente protegidas pelo sistema operacional.

Você pode executar comandos `NodeJs` mesmo dentro de pastas protegidas do sistema más se este for o caso deve iniciar o `prompt` de comando (CMD) com privilégios de administrador.

Comment: obrigada! fiz o q falou e funcionou!!!! vlwwww